# Rails Octopus Gem - Log which database queried

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, octopus

Does anyone have a way to check which database is being queried from ActiveRecord using Octopus Gem?

I want to check whether the read requests are actually hitting slave database and not master database.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the gem [source code](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/blob/v0.8.5/lib/octopus/log_subscriber.rb), I believe that Octopus already **logs the current shard** it sends the ActiveRecord query against, by default. You need to set your Rails logger to the `:debug` level and then you should see a green prefix `[Shard: the_db] ...` on each debug line, including the SQL printings.

See also this [gem's spec](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/blob/v0.8.5/lib/octopus/log_subscriber.rb) for using the logging feature.